# How to create bean from java config instead of context bean, if class has private constructor?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

```
<bean id="beanTest" class="com.test.BeanTest">
   <property name="param" value="test"/>
</bean>

@configuration
public class JavaConfig {

@Bean
public BeanTest beanTest() throws Exception {
    Constructor constructor = BeanTest.class
            .getDeclaredConstructor();
    constructor.setAccessible(true);
    BeanTest beanTest = (BeanTest) constructor
            .newInstance();
    beanTest.setParam("test");
    return beanTest;
  }

}
```

Assumptions - 
1) Bean test is in some other library.
2) BeanTest has setter for param but constructor is private.

Problem statement-
I want to remove applicationContext.xml file and wanted to use java config class to define the bean.

Solution-
I tried successfully using reflection.

is that the correct solution or by some other way we can solve this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post example of your java config?

Comment: @22kar please review the edits.

Comment: Does BeanTest has some builder methods? If so, then use them instead of reflection.

Comment: Spring internally uses reflections to instantiate beans with private constructors.  Your approach seems right.

Answer (score 0):

It has private constructor for reason. Creator didn't that class to be instantiated. This often happens

- for utility classes (with static methods), where you can use them directly via static class (e.g. org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.readFileToString). You don't need to register them as beans.
- for classes holding context/data, that should be present only once in your application (Singleton pattern). In this case, creating second instance would break that library or cause unpredictable behavior. Such libraries often provide way to retrieve this singleton instance: E.g. `org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder.getContext()` for spring security. You can register that instance as bean:

  ```
  @Bean
  public SecurityContext securityContext() {
       return SecurityContextHolder.getContext();
  }
  ```

If neither of above cases are the case for library you are trying to use. I would question if library is designed well and would probably try to avoid it in my application.